# How to vectorize row-wise diagonalization of a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave, vectorization

I have an n-by-m matrix that I want to convert to a mn-by-m matrix, with each m-by-m block of the result containing the diagonal of each row.

For example, if the input is:

```
[1 2; 3 4; 5 6]
```

the output should be:

```
[1 0; 0 2; 3 0; 0 4; 5 0; 0 6]
```

Of course, I don't want to assemble the matrix step by step myself with a `for` loop.
Is there a vectorized and simple way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a vectorized way to do this, create the linear indices of the diagonal elements into the resulting matrix, and assign directly.

```
%# create some input data
inArray = [10 11;12 13;14 15];

%# make the index array
[nr,nc]=size(inArray);

idxArray = reshape(1:nr*nc,nc,nr)';
idxArray = bsxfun(@plus,idxArray,0:nr*nc:nr*nc^2-1);

%# create output
out = zeros(nr*nc,nc);
out(idxArray) = inArray(:);

out =

    10     0
     0    11
    12     0
     0    13
    14     0
     0    15
```

Comment: Can you explain what `bsxfun` does?

Comment: @ja72: bsxfun automatically expands arrays so that you can e.g. add a n-by-1 array to a n-by-m array. The handle at the beginning (`@plus` in this case) tells which operation to perform. It's faster and much more convenient that using `repmat`.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple vectorized solution, assuming `X` is the input matrix:

```
Y = repmat(eye(size(X, 2)), size(X, 1), 1);
Y(find(Y)) = X;
```

Another alternative is to use [`sparse`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html), and this can be written as a neat one-liner:

```
Y = full(sparse(1:numel(X), repmat(1:size(X, 2), 1, size(X, 1)), X'));
```

Comment: +1: this must have been accepted solution; 2d step is another amazing application of Octave matrix indexes

Comment: This solution is preferable to using bsxfun because it doesn't require function passing so it can be better optimized in native code.  Also, consider making Y sparse.

Comment: @dspyz `sparse` is a good suggestion, thanks. I've added another solution :-)

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way I see to do this is actually quite simple, using simple index referencing and the reshape function:

```
I = [1 2; 3 4; 5 6];
J(:,[1,4]) = I;
K = reshape(J',2,6)';
```

If you examine `J`, it looks like this:

```
J =
     1     0     0     2
     3     0     0     4
     5     0     0     6
```

Matrix `K` is just what wanted:

```
K =
     1     0
     0     2
     3     0
     0     4
     5     0
     0     6
```

As Eitan T has noted in the comments, the above is specific to the example, and doesn't cover the general solution. So below is the general solution, with m and n as described in the question.

```
J(:,1:(m+1):m^2) = I;
K=reshape(J',m,m*n)';
```

If you want to test it to see it working, just use

```
I=reshape(1:(m*n),m,n)';
```

Note: if J already exists, this can cause problems. In this case, you need to also use

```
J=zeros(n,m^2);
```

Comment: -1: This triggers an error: "Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.". Even if it would've worked, that's not even the correct output.

Comment: The dimension mismatch is due to a typo - I said J(:,1:4), but it was supposed to say J(:,[1,4]). I transcribed it incorrectly, is all. The error has been corrected, and it should work as expected. As for the output, if you pay attention, I was describing the matrix J, which is NOT the final output. K is the output, and it looks exactly like what litro requested... at least, it is on Octave.

Comment: It works now, so I've removed the downvote. However note that it is not generic because it works only when `I` has two columns.

Comment: True, it's not generic, as I had written it. I'll add a more general solution, because it does generalise pretty well.

Comment: Done. Fairly confident that it should work as expected. Don't think there's any typo.

Comment: No typo. +1 for your approach. However, note that you'll have to add `clear J` before assigning new values into it in order to make sure that everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the most computationally efficient solution, but here's a 1-liner using `kron`:

```
A = [1 2; 3 4; 5 6];
B = diag(reshape(A', 6, 1) * kron(ones(3, 1), eye(2))
% B = 
%     1     0
%     0     2
%     3     0
%     0     4
%     5     0
%     0     6
```

This can be generalized if A is n x m:

```
diag(reshape(A.', n*m, 1)) * kron(ones(n,1), eye(m))
```